# Prove that X is compact if and only if X is a finite set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a set of real numbers such that for each a∈X, a is an isolated point in X. Prove that X is  compact if and only if X is a finite set. (Hint: see the  proof of theBolzano-Weierstrass Theorem)

Comment: The hint seems needless to me. This is an exercise in pushing around definitions. Choose an open set for each point that witnesses the fact that it is isolated. Show that we can only obtain a finite subcover of this cover if the set is finite.

Comment: If $X$ is finite then $X$ is compact (obvious). If $X$ is discrete and compact, extract a finite subcover of $\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Each $a$ is isolated which means that there is a neighborhood $N_{a}$ so that $N_{a}\cap X$ = {a}. If X is compact these $N_{a}$ form a cover of $X$ with no proper subcover, therefore there must be finitely many such $N_{a}$ and hence finitely many $a$, so $X$ is finite. If X is finite the set of distinct sets over X is finite call the totality of such sets J, any open cover of $X$ can find a finite subcover by discarding any repeated sets so that all sets are distinct, then there can be no more than J sets in this subcover, so every open cover has a finite subcover and X is compact.